# Python class if of type 'None'

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm creating a small project. However, every time I try to create an instance of a class `TwitterClient` and assign it to the variable `api`, trying to call methods from `api` returns 'NoneType object has no attribute (function name). I've looked at what others have done regarding this topic, but so far, changing the parameters of the TwitterClient class hasn't worked. Perhaps my understanding is off, but why is a class being considered a NoneType object? After I run main(), I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXjTd.png).
Here's my code:

```html
def TwitterClient():

    def __init__(self):
        

        api_key = '-------'
        api_key_secret = '----------'

        bearer_token = '--------------'

        access_token = '---------------'
        access_token_secret = '-----------------'
        

        try:

            self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

            self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)
        except:
            print("Error: Authentication Failed")
            
    
       
    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())
    

    def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet):
        

        analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet))
        
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
            return '+'
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
            return 'n'
        else:
            return '-'
    

    def get_tweets(self, query, count=10):
    

        tweets = []
        
        try:

            fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q = query, count = count)
            
            for tweet in fetched_tweets:

                parsed_tweets = {}

                parsed_tweets['text'] = tweet.text

                parsed_tweet['sentiemnt'] = tweet.sentiment
                

                if tweet.retweet_count > 0:

                    if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                        tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
                else:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
            
            return parsed_tweets
        
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print("Error : " + str(e))
```

```html
def main():

    api = TwitterClient()
    

    tweets = api.get_tweets(query = "etc", count = 10)
    
    
    
    
if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Comment: You need to define your class as `class TwitterClient:`. Currently by using `def` you're defining a function

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you didn't define a class, but also didn't properly initialize your function either. But also, tweepy no longer has an API.search() function but is now broken up into API.search_tweets(), API.search_users(), API.search_geo(), and a couple of premium ones that I don't have any experience with since access is both limited and not free. Since it looks like you're using OAuth1.0's user context, and Oauth 2.0 also has a user context handler, you should also know that the OAuthHandler function has been deprecated and you should explicitly call OAuth1UserHandler (or Oauth2UserHandler if you want to use that), since they take different parameters.

The simplest way to fix what you have would be something like:

```
import tweepy

class TwitterClient(object):

    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret):
        self.authclient = tweepy.Oauth1UserHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
        self.api = tweepy.API(self.authclient)

    def get_tweets(self, query, count=10):
        fetched_tweets = self.api.search_tweets(q=query, count=count)
        # add in whatever parsing code you want here, since it returns a collection anyway, fetched_tweets['statuses'] is a list of returned tweets, and you can iterate through their 'text' field if you so wish via list comprehension
```

Also, I think that the v2 API now has a recent search endpoint that is going to end up being the preferred way of searching for free users, since it returns the last 100 tweets in reverse chronological order, if there are tweets, you shouldn't come up empty with the query. A lot of us are grandfathered into Elevated Access while Twitter is clearly trying to deprecate at some point v1.1 so it's entirely possible that not only does the api return different results for you and me but there's no real telling as to how long they'll keep the current endpoints working as is, so definitely keep an eye out for breaking changes.